# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 6.4 Inserting Random Duplicates

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

I have an issue where Entity Framework 6.4.8 using ASP.NET MVC 4 and .NET Framework 4.8 will randomly insert duplicate records (2-5).

Attached is an abbreviated version of my code broken down into all the multiple and essential components.

Process that performs processing the answers and saving, this saves all at once so should only be 1 entry per answer

```
public bool UpdateBusinessQuestionAnswers(BusinessQuestionAnswerServiceViewModel businessQuestionAnswerDto)
{
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            int applicationId = businessQuestionAnswerDto.ApplicationId;
            int businessId = businessQuestionAnswerDto.BusinessId;
            var dtoAnswers = businessQuestionAnswerDto.BusinessQuestionAnswers;

            foreach (var answer in dtoAnswers)
                 kyEntityProcessor.ProcessAnswers(applicationId, answer.Id, businessId, answer.Response);

            kyGenericRepo.Save();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Debug(ex);
        }

        return success;
}
```

The kyEntityProcessor -> `ProcessAnswers` function:

```
public void ProcessAnswers(int applicationId, int questionId, int businessId, string response)
{
    var answer = kyGenericRepo.FindByApp<KpBusinessQuestionAnswer>(applicationId, x => x.QuestionId == questionId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (answer != null)
    {
        answer.Response = response;
        kyGenericRepo.Edit(answer);              
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
    {                  
        var newAnswer = NewBusinessQuestionAnswer(businessId, applicationId, questionId, response);
        kyGenericRepo.Add(newAnswer);                              
    }                       
}
```

The `NewBusinessQuestionAnswer` function:

```
public KpBusinessQuestionAnswer NewBusinessQuestionAnswer(int? businessId, int? applicationId, int questionId, string response)
{
    var newAnswer = new KpBusinessQuestionAnswer
        {
            AppId = applicationId,
            BusinessId = businessId,
            QuestionId = questionId,
            Response = response,
            IsDeleted = false
        };

    return newAnswer;
}
```

The `kyGenericRepo.Add` function:

```
public T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        var _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        return _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         logger.Debug(ex);
         return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a for loop that processes all the question, and I have verified there is only 1 instance for each question id thus there should only be 1 entry added to the database table. 99% of the time this is the case, basically out of 308,768 records I have 5,656 duplicates and a total of about 30 unique question ids that seem to be replicated. So it happens at random for about 30 questions out of the 220 total.

About 75% of the time the timestamps on these duplicates are the exact same the remaining 25% of the time they are different by ~200ms.

The data is submitted from an AngularJS Form to a .NET Framework API that performs the saving process to a SQL Server 2014 database. This also only fires once, meaning there are no duplicate submissions being sent to the API at the same time.

I have disabled the submit button after the initial click, and this reduced double clicking submissions but I am still getting duplicates. My guess is something is happening within EF or my code that is causing these duplicates to continue happening.

Any help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: Why not select a separate attribute and set it as a unique index? If there is no suitable attribute, you can also add a new one specifically as a unique index. Then you go and catch the update failure error.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I am slightly confused, are you meaning in the database or in the code? Why would I need to do that, exactly? The problem is the records are duplicated upon insertion into the database.

Comment: (Nevermind. Seems like you have already covered there possibilities.) *Might be a race condition. Is it possible that someone double-clicking a submit button might be triggering two separate processes, both of which find no existing answer, and thus both are saving new answers. My other thought is: Can dtoAnswers contain duplicate answers, and after the first is processed as a new answer, the second is processed and the `FindByApp()` check does not see the (not-yet-saved) first answer?*

Comment: @rientelfon What I mean is that you can generate a set of numbers based on the inserted data when inserting data, and then use it as a unique index in the database, so that this set of numbers will become unique. Or you can query the database before inserting data. Of course, this will consume more performance. If the returned result is empty, the insertion can be successful.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT This is really not necessary, I am not sure what this would solve except creating 2 unique indexes to search. I already have a unique index, the issue is that it will duplicate the entries randomly. From what i can tell it is a very small amount, but it will happen and I don't know why.

Comment: @TN I have added a check to ensure that there are no duplicates, just in case. It will report if there are.

Comment: From the code level, adding a check when submitting to ensure there are no duplicates is a good solution.